# Removing duplicates from an unsorted linked list

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

How to remove duplicates from an unsorted linked list without using temporary buffers?
I can't think of any method.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question does belong to a datastructures site, not SO

Comment: Check each node all the other nodes that follow it. When you find a duplicate, remove the following node. Hopefully the person who posted the answer below will elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

There is the O(n^2) method, of course, that would work without buffers. I could elaborate if you like.

Comment: Yes, you should elaborate. Otherwise this answer is useless because it assumes that the OP knows what the O(n^2) method is.

Comment: no problem with the O(n^2) but i need to remove duplicates without using temporary buffers.

Comment: Where exactly are you using temporary buffers? (Maybe I am misunderstanding what you mean by temp buffers)  I suppose if you would share your approach in detail, I could help.